# NZSQL/CODE - How to use PRINT in Netezza

Tags: sql, netezza

We are using Aginity Workbench for Netezza SQL and I was wondering if anyone knows of a equivalent in NZSQL for the TSQL "PRINT" function?

We use it for printing errors when someone tries to execute a query that would rewrite data when it shouldnt, and the only solution I am finding is using netezza command line "-t".

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use RAISE to do this, as documented [here](https://www-304.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSULQD_7.2.0/com.ibm.nz.sproc.doc/c_sproc_aborting_messages.html).

Here is an example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RAISE_DEMO()
RETURNS VARCHAR(ANY)
EXECUTE AS OWNER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE
MYNAME varchar;
BEGIN
MYNAME := 'SCOTT';

RAISE NOTICE 'Hello, %', MYNAME;

END;
END_PROC;
```

---

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=> call raise_demo();
NOTICE:  Hello, SCOTT
 RAISE_DEMO
------------

(1 row)
```

If you change NOTICE to EXCEPTION, then the execution will stop.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE RAISE_DEMO()
RETURNS VARCHAR(ANY)
EXECUTE AS OWNER
LANGUAGE NZPLSQL AS
BEGIN_PROC
DECLARE
MYNAME varchar;
BEGIN
MYNAME := 'SCOTT';

RAISE EXCEPTION 'Hello, %, this is an exception', MYNAME;

RAISE NOTICE 'You should not see this message';

END;
END_PROC;
```

---

```
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=>  call raise_demo();
ERROR:  Hello, SCOTT, this is an exception
TESTDB.ADMIN(ADMIN)=>
```

This behavior is in documented in the link I provided at the top.

Comment: Thank you for the response, Scott. Is there any way to make the raise notice stop the query based on logic? What we used in TSQL was: 
IF Col1=Col2 BEGIN PRINT N' My Custom Comment Here' RETURN  END ELSE <the query>

Comment: Edited the answer to cover that.

Comment: Thanks again for all your help, Scott. Much appreciated. Going to mess around with this, I think it will work for us!